# Upload file to server without multipart in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I want to upload the image to the server.The services for the server is written in .NET. Now server asks me to send the image as bytes of data not as multipart.I am uploading the file by below code.I get response as file uploaded but image is not shown.

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
          [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
          NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
          NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
          //NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
          //[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

          [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"host_pic\"; filename=\"parkN.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:postData];
          [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

          // close form
          [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
          [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Please explain what could be the issue.How can i uplaod such file.

Comment: check with this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7289185/4831524

Comment: Then how to send that byte array to server.Can you please update mycode?

Comment: for that check this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/38263070/4831524

Comment: as i mentioned earlier webservice does not support multipart

Comment: I updated as a ans @iOSGuy

Answer (score 0):

then you could try to POST JSON format.

```c
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<YOUR SERVER>"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSString *byteArray = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: byteArray, @"host_pic",
                     @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
                     nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: API guy told me i don't have to send any key as host_pic with upload request

Comment: then you have to follow with __multipart/form-data__ uploading of image

Comment: API does not support multipart form data & can't send any key

Comment: is there any API token for that API?? And the code as you used **NSURLSession** method?